# Extract all cell references in excel with regex in java

Tags: java, regex, excel, substring, excel-formula

have excel data and formulars like:

- (S10+S14+S18+S22+S26+S30+S34)
- E10+E11+SUM(E10;E14:E17)*E18-IF(E19<1,E20, E21)
- SUM(E14:E19)
- S16*S15

and so on.

I want to get all the cell references out of the strings.
Like in this Example: "E10+E11+SUM(E10;E14:E17)*E18-IF(E19<1,E20, E21)"

**I want the output substring like "E10 E11 ... E21"** or separated with ",".

I tested a lot with regex but can't get a valid result.
I am using this code:

```
String formulaString = "E10+E11+SUM(E10;E14:E17)*E18-IF(E19<1,E20, E21)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("REGEX");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(formulaString);
```

I have tried the following regex:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/815e819c-f0f2-4a53-8407-98b0f7f116e2/regex-to-extract-list-of-cell-references-from-excel-formula?forum=csharpgeneral

REGEX: (\w+|)?\$?(?:\bXF[A-D]|X[A-E][A-Z]|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z])\$?(?:104857[0-6]|10485[0-6]\d|1048[0-4]\d{2}|104[0-7]\d{3}|10[0-3]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{1,5}|[1-9])d?\b(:\s?\$?(?:\bXF[A-D]|X[A-E][A-Z]|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z])\$?(?:104857[0-6]|10485[0-6]\d|1048[0-4]\d{2}|104[0-7]\d{3}|10[0-3]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{1,5}|[1-9])d?\b)?

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc179984-4fc8-4346-90e8-1649a23b6afe/regex-solution-to-id-excel-cell-references-in-an-excel-formula-string?forum=regexp

REGEX: \$?\b([A-Z]|[A-H][A-Z]|I[A-V])\$?([1-9]\d{0,3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-6])\b([:\s]\$?\b([A-Z]|[A-H][A-Z]|I[A-V])\$?([1-9]\d{0,3}|[1-5]\d{4}|6[0-4]\d{3}|65[0-4]\d{2}|655[0-2]\d|6553[0-6])\b)?

For some of the formular they are working, but not for all.

I hope anyone can help me or give me a tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[]args){
String formula = "E10+E11+SUM(E10;E14:E17)*E18-IF(E19<1,E20, E21)";
String output="";


for(String c: formula.split("[^A-z0-9]+")){
    if(isCell(c)){
               output+=c+" ";
    }
}


}

private static boolean isCell(String current){
   boolean hasLetter = false;
   boolean hasNumber = false;

for(int i=0; i<current.length() && (!hasLetter || !hasNumber); i++){


    if(current.charAt(i)>=65 && current.charAt(i)<=90){


        hasLetter=true;
    }
    else if(current.charAt(i)>='0' && current.charAt(i)<='9'){

        hasNumber=true;
    }
}

return hasLetter && hasNumber;
}
```

Comment: Not a good answer. There are function names that could be confused for cell letters (e.g. SUM), and your code also doesn't take cell numbers into account (e.g. it should return `E10` and not just `E`).

Comment: The answer is not matching the problem. But thanks anyway.. Maybe I can get the answer easier by split by regex... I will try something out.

Comment: My apologies. I forgot about the numbers. I have edited the answer to include the numbers.

Comment: @Solace That's better, but it still doesn't address the other issue I mentioned - you need to take into account the built-in functions, such as `Yr1990()`

Comment: Perhaps OP can write a function that checks whether or not the current String is a cell.

Comment: 1 Character and 1-7 numbers,
2 Character and 1-7 numbers,
3 Character and 1-7 numbers
 - 
This sould be the right classification for cells - the only problem is that I am not able to get it working with a regex.

Comment: Looking at the samples...it appears that each cell is a capital letter followed by two numbers. You can filter them out in the for loop.

Comment: Thanks. The example seems to be working, but a cell can also look like ee1111 or XFD1048576. I provided the classification in my last comment.. I will try to improve. Maybe it helps :)

Comment: Can a function name have both letters and numbers? Or are functions strictly letter only?

Comment: There are some. Like "DEC2BIN" but for my requirement it is not important to consider these few exceptions.

Comment: If that is the case then you can define a cell to be anything that has both a number and a letter. I have updated the function.

Answer (score 0):

On the first thread you linked to, the regex you put below the link is nowhere to be found on the page. Were you really using a regex from that page? The regex that was suggested was:

```
(\w+|)?\$?(?:\bXF[A-D]|X[A-E][A-Z]|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z])\$?(?:104857[0-6]|10485[0-6]\d|1048[0-4]\d{2}|104[0-7]\d{3}|10[0-3]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{1,5}|[1-9])d?\b(:\s?\$?(?:\bXF[A-D]|X[A-E][A-Z]|[A-W][A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{2}|[A-Z])\$?(?:104857[0-6]|10485[0-6]\d|1048[0-4]\d{2}|104[0-7]\d{3}|10[0-3]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{1,5}|[1-9])d?\b)?
```

Try that.

Also, it would help to know what *specific* strings don't get matched correctly, since you mentioned that some of them work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I missed something with copy and paste... But I have tried the string you provided. With this String, the following testdata are working: S16*S15 and E10+E11+SUM(E10;E14:E17)*E18-IF(E19<1,E20, E21)

Comment: @user3373589 But what are some strings that _aren't_ working?

Comment: for example (S10+S14+S18+S22+S26+S30+S34) and SUM(E14:E19)